# Is there a way to change the log-in sound

Tags: 11.04, sound, login

I don't like the current log-in sound in 11.04 and I want my own sound.

Can I change the log-in sound?

Answer (score 1):

Make an .ogg file and put it in `/usr/share/sounds/ubuntu/stereo/`

Go into Start-up applications and change the login sound id to the one you want:

```
/usr/bin/canberra-gtk-play -–id=”desktop-login” -–description=”GNOME Login”
```

Comment: How does this command know what file to play?

Comment: what if the sound is mono?

Comment: the file must replace one called `desktop-login.ogg `

Answer (score 1):

In the *startup applications*, search for *Gnome Login Sound* and replace the command by this: `canberra-gtk-play --file X`.
Replace X by the file you want to have as the new login sound.